# HTML5 Bing Maps and Geolocation

Tags: geolocation, bing-maps

I'm working on an windows 8 app in html5 and now I'm stuck with the map that is going to find the users location I don't know whats wrong, it says it some error I hope someone can help me because I have more to work on and i have a deadline on this project

map.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>BingMapsJSIntro</title>

    <script src="http://dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>

    <!-- BingMapsJSIntro references -->
    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/js/default.js"></script>

    <!-- Bing Maps references -->
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="ms-appx:///Bing.Maps.JavaScript//js/veapicore.js"></script>

    <!-- Our Bing Maps JavaScript Code -->
    <script src="/js/bing.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="myMap"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

bing.js

```
    var map;

function showMap(position) {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map($("mymap")[0],
    {
        credentials: "MYBINGMAPCODE",
        center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(latitude, longitude),
        mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road,
        zoom: 10
    });

    var center = map.getCenter();
    var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(center, { width: 50, height: 50, draggable: false });
    map.entities.push(pin);
}

//Initialization logic for loading the map control
(function () {
    function initialize() {
        Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Map', { callback: GetMap });
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initialize, false);
})();
```

Comment: Unhandled exception at line 23, column 9 in ms-appx://fe56a029-c8e7-41e5-a755-b22871affb67/js/bing.js
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'GetMap' is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Your modules callback method "*GetMap*" is non-existant in the code you provided.

```
Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Map', { callback: GetMap });
```

You need something like...

```
function GetMap ()
{
   var mapOptions = { credentials:"<Insert Your Bing Maps Key Here>" }
   var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("myMap"), mapOptions );
}
```